# React | Class | Arrow functions binds by "react" build or not

Tags: reactjs

Arrow functions in classes, they bind by react build or not? One guy told me that arrow functions bind by a react build. He said we don't need to bind arrow functions because react did it for us. Is it so or not? But at the same time, we know that we don't need to bind arrow functions due to they don't have their own "this", due to their nature

UPDATE:
It looks like he was right. Take a look at this [link](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=true&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDCIEtgGt6RgUwB4BcMDsATGAJQzGBwDpYB7AWwAdb8CdoBvAKGmmBYg4ATgFdKtIQApGQ2owgBKTj17QIIxhiky5i3ioC-Klb1BJkAUQBubaAF5okpXYB8y1av74ItEBiogtADmkgDkZijWbKEKANwm0Aax0Ma8QgSEWk7uquk4IkL4jgkAPABGIjg4LNAs8OZ2HDgAFggQVBGWNvg4Bi71KNAAshglAPQVVSwuCQpcRgZAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=true&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.20.11&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D) (**babel mode is spec and force all transforms**):

Short example:

```
clickEvent = () => {
  console.log('clickEvent');
};
```

Turn into this:

```
_defineProperty(
  _assertThisInitialized(_this),
  "clickEvent",
  function () {
    _newArrowCheck(this, _this2);
    console.log("clickEvent");
  }.bind(this)
);
```

But if we don't transpile to es5, then we don't bind it. There is such a part of a code:

```
_defineProperty(this, "clickEvent", () => {
  console.log("clickEvent");
});
```

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: One guy has a really poor understanding of this topic.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking either

Comment: @Thomas, I guess he was right, take a look the link above

Comment: And you're wondering now why babel will transform your code when you check "force all transforms". Or are you wondering that babel is binding the function after you forced it to replace the arrow function with a regular one?

Comment: I'm interested in the inner mechanisms of react. To understand react really binds or really not